# jQuery run on elements loaded via ajax in previous function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm aware of the use of `.ajaxComplete` however the code I am working with is independent from the function that runs the ajax.

I'm also aware of `.live` however this is deprecated.

I have a function which loads in some HTML, including a div called `main.home`

In a different function, I want to make `main.home` `.slideDown`

```
/* First function loads the HTML */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#quiz-section").load("home.php");
    $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $( ".inner-wrap" ).fadeIn(2000);
    });
});

/* Second function called on button click */
function nextQuestion(page){
    $("main.home").slideDown("fast");
}
```

`.slideDown` does not seem to work but no errors are presented in the console. I believe that maybe it cannot find the element `main.home`  because it is loaded via ajax?

Any advice appreciated.

Edit to add the call for `nextQuestion` as requested:

```
<div class="button pink" onclick="nextQuestion('q1');" >Take our 'Love Match' test</div>
```

HTML as so rudely asked for is nothing but:

```
<main class="home">
<div class="button pink" onclick="nextQuestion('q1');" >Take our 'Love Match' test</div>
</main>
```

There you go.

Comment: Where is `nextQuestion` called from? It does sound like you need to use a delegated event handler

Comment: are you missing a # or . in front of main.home ?

Comment: @overflowed nope: http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `nextQuestion` is loaded from clicking a button (using `onclick`), can confirm that the function does run correctly, have checked with a console.log and it does load the correct function, just doesn't enact the `slideDown`

Comment: @Francesca So you call it from inline onclick attribute or what?

Comment: I have added the call to `nextQuestion` above

Comment: @overflowed no `main` is valid HTML5

Comment: What returns `console.log($("main.home").length);`? You have to provide online sample to replicate issue

Comment: Can anybody explain why this question has been marked to close and how the question "does not appear to be about programming".

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.`

Comment: Basically, if you can also show your page HTML in full too, nobody will complain and any answers can be validated (there is often more than one issue) :)

Comment: That is incredibly rude. HTML has been provided and you have been reported.

Comment: That was not my intention. My apologies. Voting to close instead and deleting my answer as it cannot be confirmed with the information at hand. Good luck.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie would you have written that to a man or is it just because I'm obviously a female?

Comment: Actually I would, but have you seen most of the guys' photos on SO... I should have chosen a better audience for humour.

Comment: I think you're looking for http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What slideDown do ?

It make **visible** an **hidden element** with a slide motion.

So, you should have this :

HTML:

```
<main class="home" style="display:none;">
    Some stuff here
</main>
<div id="clickme" class="button pink">Take our 'Love Match' test</div>
```

Javascript :

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    $("main.home").slideDown("fast");
});
```

"Some stuff here" is hidden and when you click on the link, it make your element main appears with a slide motion.